# Inserting a random number into an array

Tags: array, comments

So what im trying to do is make a random offset for 'top comment', at the moment it's working great(with no offset) but I want to randomise the offset so it displays 1 of the top 5 comments by offsetting it. So I was either going to use a range or an array; whichever works best.

Everything is ok on the first two lines - I can print and echo it fine, but when it comes to using the variable within my second array it just defaults back to the 0 offset.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated - code below.

```
$numbers = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5);
$random_key = array_rand($numbers, 1);
$comments = get_comments(array('orderby' => 'comment_karma', 'number' => 20, 'status' => 'approve', 'offset' => '.random_key.'));
```

Comment: Only a line will suffice: `$comments = get_comments(array('orderby' => 'comment_karma', 'number' => 20, 'status' => 'approve', 'offset' => rand(1, 5) ));`

Comment: you're passing a string with value `.random_key.` as offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

offset parameter of [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function accepts integer values for more information visit [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

so your get_comments function call should be as following.

```
$numbers = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5);
$random_key = array_rand($numbers, 1);
$comments = get_comments(array('orderby' => 'comment_karma', 'number' => 20, 'status' => 'approve', 'offset' => $random_key));
```

Comment: it should maybe also be pointed out that `array_rand` returns a *key* and not a value, they just happen to align in the example array.

Comment: Yes but in this case the keys and values are same.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I am quite new to PHP and have received some quite unique requests. Thanks alot for your quick response.